# Arrays are not equal after converting numpy array to byte array and back to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I want to send an image which was imported by opencv imread to another computer via socket. But the data received and the data sent are not equal.

I have converted the numpy array data which I got by imread and converted it to byte array in order to send it via the socket. And then 
i have converted the byte array which was received at the other end back to the numpy array. But I can't view the image from the received data.

This is the code snippet in the senders end

```py
im = cv2.imread('view.jpg')
stringimage = np.array_str(im)
byteimage = str.encode(stringimage)
sock.sendto(byteimage,("127.0.0.1",5002))
```

This is the code snippet in the receivers end

```py
byteimage,addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
decoded = bytes.decode(byteimage)
backstring = np.array(decoded)
cv2.imshow('RealSense', backstring)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I got this error

> TypeError: mat data type = 19 is not supported

for this line of code

```py
cv2.imshow('RealSense', backstring)
```

**Update**

After getting the suggestions bellow and referring some other materials I have come up with a solution which is working for my scenario.

Image senders side

```py
#color_image is my opencv image

retval, data = cv2.imencode('.jpg', color_image, ENCODE_PARAMS)
b64_bytes = base64.b64encode(data)
b64_string = b64_bytes.decode()
sock.sendto(str.encode(b64_string), ("127.0.0.1", 5002))
```

Image receivers side

```py
data, addr = sock.recvfrom(60000)
img = imread(io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(data)))
```

Please tell me if there is any bad coding in my solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar question was helpfully answered [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54005252/4604529)

The issue is that constructing the numpy array from a string doesn't parse the data as a float/int the way you wrote it (and converting to a string to send the data is unnecessary).

Here's a simplified example to apply that solution:

```
import numpy as np
from io import BytesIO

a = np.array([1, 2])
b = BytesIO()
np.save(b, a)

"""-----send the data-----"""
# send(b.getvalue())


data = BytesIO(b.getvalue())
c = np.load(data)
print(a)
print(c)
```

Resulting in:

```
[1 2]
[1 2]
```

Comment: b.getvalue() can't be send through the socket. I tried `sock.send(b.getvalue(),("127.0.0.1",5005))` . But I get this error "TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)"

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have come up with a solution. And updated it in the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> byteimage,addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)

This limits your buffer size to 1024 bytes.

Read [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recvfrom)

Comment: I suspect the `np.array_str` command is the root of the issue. But all this is unnecessary. It seems like you want to send the image from one socket to another. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51921631/how-to-send-and-receive-webcam-stream-using-tcp-sockets-in-python)

Comment: Thank you for note that point out. I have increased the buffer size to 256,000 bytes . But the issue remains same. My image size is 71,470 bytes

Comment: I had to compress the image and increase the buffer size in order to send the image. Thank you for the suggestion.